# Unable to find source of ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, arrays

I need some help to identify why this code is throwing an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`:

```java
public class palindrome 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        String name = "Michael Knight";

        char ch[] = name.toCharArray();
        int size = name.length();

        for(int i = 0; i<size; i++) {
            //System.out.println(size);
            System.out.println(ch[i]);

            for(int j=size; j>=0; j--) {
                System.out.println(ch[j]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you know that you can use a [`StringBuilder.reverse()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#reverse()) function to reverse a `String`?

Comment: Thanks for that, I'll try it out. I'm a beginner Java programmer trying to teach myself so every little helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ch[j]` is out of bounds when `j==size`, since the indices go from 0 to size-1.

It should be :

```
        for(int j=size-1; j>=0; j--){
            System.out.println(ch[j]);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

In the `for` loop, the `j` starts at index `j=size` which is already out of array bounds since the array starts from `0` to `size - 1`, thus `ch[j]` throws an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

The correct way to loop in reverse should be:

```
for(int j= (size - 1); j>=0; j--){
    System.out.println(ch[j]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try like this;

```
public class palindrome{

   public static void main(String []arg$){

    String name = "Michael Knight";

    char ch[] = name.toCharArray();
    int size = name.length();

    for(int i = 0; i<size; i++){
        //System.out.println(size);
        System.out.println(ch[i]);

        for(int j=size-1; j>=0; j--){
            System.out.println(ch[j]);
        }

    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int j=size; j>=0; j--) {
            System.out.println(ch[j]);
```

j=size is out of bounds . 
The last index of array is size-1. 
j should be initialized with the last index of array in this case.